# How to display/hide custom buttons conditionally for Contacts in Salesforce application

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

I am new to Salesforce. I have added two custom buttons XXX & YYY in my Salesforce application. But I want to display/hide these two buttons based on conditions for different contacts.

For example: If the contact is related to Firm 'A' then we need to show only the custom button XXX in the contact layout, for contacts related to other firms should be able to see only the custom button YYY in the contact layout.

Please help me with how to implement the above requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Generally such config questions are better suited to dedicated salesforce.stackexchange.com. more admins over there = you'll get an answer faster.

Answer (score 1):

Read up about "dynamic actions" in the help. There's also trailhead (free self-paced training module with gamification and stuff), scroll down to screenshots: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/spring-21-release-highlights-no-code/learn-whats-new-in-spring-21-no-code

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your solution will work only for the Lightning experience, but I want to implement the same functionality in Salesforce classic as well. So requesting you to please let me know if we have any common solution for both Classic & Lightning. Thanks

Comment: Not on the normal page layout. There used to be a trick for classic but patched 6 years ago: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/10516/799. For universal solution you could make 2 record types & 2 different layouts for them (bit overkill, just to display one or another button). Or embed a Visualforce page with the button and use `rendered=...` in that page's code. The button won't appear in the same place as normal ones though